# Creating a multi-model in Django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to create a directed graph in Django, but each node could be a separate model, with separate fields, etc.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
from bannergraph.apps.banners.models import *

class Node(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(db_index=True, auto=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FirstNode(Node):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    next_node = UUIDField()

class SecondNode(Node):
    is_something = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_choice = UUIDField()
    second_choice = UUIDField()
```

(obviously `FirstNode` and `SecondNode` are placeholders for the more domain-specific models, but hopefully you get the point.)

So what I'd like to do is query all the subclasses at once, returning all of the ones that match. I'm not quite sure how to do this efficiently.

Things I've tried:

1. Iterating over the subclasses with queries - I don't like this, as it could get quite heavy with the number of queries.
2. Making `Node` concrete. Apparently I have to still check for each subclass, which goes back to #1.

Things I've considered:

- Making `Node` the class, and sticking a JSON blob in it. I don't like this.
- Storing pointers in an external table or system. This would mean 2 queries per UUID, where I'd ideally want to have 1, but it would probably do OK in a pinch.

So, am I approaching this wrong, or forgetting about some neat feature of Django? I'd rather not use a schemaless DB if I don't have to (the Django admin is almost essential for this project). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from `django-model-utils` is what you are looking for.

You can iterate over all your Nodes with:

```
nodes = Node.objects.filter(foo="bar").select_subclasses()
    for node in nodes:
        #logic
```

Comment: I had no idea about `django-model-utils`. There's some seriously useful stuff in there!